# SQL - Operand data type varchar is invalid for sum operator

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm running the following query and getting the Operand data type varchar is invalid for sum operator error.  The accountnature field is a varchar field, but I'm casting it as INT and I'm still getting the error.

```
SELECT
    'Qualified' =sum(case when (cast(AccountNature AS Int)) in ('a','b') then '1' end)

from agreement

group by accountnature
```

Any thoughts on what I'm doing wrong or how to fix?
Thanks.

Comment: can u say what is the actual datatype for "AccountNature" column

Comment: AccountNature (varchar(2), not null)

Comment: As of my knowledge If that particular column has values like 1,2,3,...... this can be done.But in case values like  a,b,c .....cast cannot be done i think

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try This:

```
SELECT
    'Qualified' = sum(case when AccountNature in ('a','b') then 1 ELSE 0 end)
from agreement
group by accountnature
```

Comment: were is the cast function in this

Comment: @RajaYuvi - there is no need to use cast.

Comment: Yes, I tried that and it wasn't working, that's why I went to the casting, but I think you just pointed me in the right direction.  I have a single quote around the '1'.  I just removed that and it works.

Comment: Why do you need to cast value in if you are comparing with varchar values. So no need of conversion.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
select [qualified] = sum(case when AccountNature in ('a','b') then 1 else 0 end)
from agreement
```

You don't need to cast it to integer because you're comparing to a char.